# Need assistance on setting up OTP

Tags: sms, one-time-password

We are testing an app and we are finding the the OTP is not being received on a test device - we notice that OTPs from Twilio have different headings depending on the device location (Airkey/TSM) etc and wondered what could be blocking the receipt of the otp sms.  The device has been checked and is receiving sms from other devices etc.

Thanks

OTP are being received on other test devices.